# What causes an error "git not found" for each org-agenda file when building org-agenda-list?

Tags: org-agenda, git, error

I have emacs 28.1 on my phone in F-Droid.

When I start any org-agenda population command like `org-agenda-list` or `org-agenda-list-stuck-projects` the list shows up, but also shows up this error message in *Messages* buffer:

> Error: (file-error "Searching for program" "Permission denied" "git") [19 times]

I have exactly 19 files in `org-agenda-files` variable but still cannot think of what causes this error.

All of the agenda files are in `org` directory under git source control. `git --help` shows help both in command line and in emacs shell.

The value of `find-file-hook` includes `vc-refresh-state`.

Comment: Are they all in the same directory? If so, is the directory under source control? Does it contain a `.git` subdirectory e.g.? Does it happen if you start emacs with `-Q`? If you can eliminate all the obvious stuff, then I would suggest bisecting your init file. Can you run `git --help` from the command line?

Comment: All of the agenda files are in org directory under git source control.

Comment: So presumably, you have magit configured (or perhaps the generic `vc` subsystem) and it tries to get status on the files on open, but it cannot execute `git` (because not installed? incorrectly installed? incorrectly configured? only you can find that out).

Comment: There is nothing shown in *Org Agenda* when running emacs with `-Q`. `magit` is not installed, `vc` is, but I never installed it, use it or configured. I don't have such problem on any Ubuntu or Windows sharing almost the same init file, only on termux. Something related to permissions, I think.

Comment: What's the value of `find-file-hook`? Does it include `vc-refresh-state`? If present, what happens if you delete that from `find-file-hook` ? Please update the question with your findings (just as you did with the the first comment - thanks for that!): do not reply in comments.

Comment: It may well be that permissions are the problem, but I don't know anything about F-Droid or termux to be able to help. Let's hope that my previous comment about `find-file-hook` leads somewhere.

Comment: Well, you ask not to reply in comments but all is left to write, that you were right and deleting `vc-refresh-state` from `find-file-hook` solves the problem. Would you form this as an answer, please?